# How to save cache in device Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter, this is my first project in Flutter. I want to do a project that once data are loaded from **API**, they're cached in the device. Next time it can be loaded very fast even if my device is **offline**. I here that can using **Dio** package with dio cache manager package for caching server's json response. And then using cache image package to cache images. Anyone can give me some example how to write the code? Thanks in advance

Comment: why not save the data in sqlite db... it is local to user's device

Comment: you can use [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter).

Comment: @DAMMAK thank you for your reply, you means that save my API response into sqlite? Sorry I am first time using flutter

Comment: @JohnJoe Thank you for your reply. My data is from API, also can use is package? Sorry I am first time using flutter

Comment: use shared preferences to store response

Comment: @qing Yes you can. I using `chopper` instead of `dio`, can use `moor` to store too.

Answer (score 4):

Another best way for caching in flutter is the use of the hive. [image]And it  retrieves data faster than Sqflite and Shared preferences

For example, you can check this GitHub repo:https://github.com/shashiben/Anime-details

This will show how to cache the rest API data into the hive and for the next time it will show data from the hive.

I think this answer helped you

Comment: my API data is in pagination. Hive also can save it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i'd recommend the sqflite package for flutter, i've just figured out how to use it to solve this same issue! I learnt it using this YouTube video: https://youtu.be/1BwjNEKD8g8.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I want to do my project similar like facebook. When offline the post still maintain at there. If online can load new post. All data is from API. It also can use sqlite?

Comment: I don't know about that...I'm still new to coding! I just know that in my project i wanted to only save data locally, and sqflite worked great for that. Sorry i can't be of more help!

Answer (score 0):

Try shared preferences https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences,

Just Decode your response as **string** and save to sharePreference, 
and Encode that String to Object when you need.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'; 

//storing response as string
SharedPreferences sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            Map decode_options = jsonDecode(jsonString);
            String user = jsonEncode(User.fromJson(decode_options));
            sharedPref.setString('user', user);//storing

//getting string and converting into Object
SharedPreferences sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            Map userMap = jsonDecode(sharedPref.getString('user')); //retriving
            var user = User.fromJson(userMap);

    class User {
      final String name;
      final String age;

      User({this.name, this.age});

      factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
        return new User(
            name: parsedJson['name'] ?? "",
            age: parsedJson['age'] ?? "");
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        return {
          "name": this.name,
          "age": this.age
        };
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, Can I know where the jsonString come from? Because I get the error with Undefined name 'jsonString'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: jsonstring is your response json from service call

Comment: I need to put SharedPreferences  at model class code here or http response there?

Comment: use ShrPref in screen "eg: Loginpage.dart" class where you get the response

Comment: Sir, I put my code at above, I already add the SharedPreferences into code but when I offline it show loading only. Can you check is I put the SharedPreferences wrongly?